# How to Add/Append content(div/img tag etc) for a div using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How to Add/Append content(div/img tag etc) for a div using `Jquery`

i want it to insert in "#contentSlider"

```
$('#slider').after('<div id="nav" class="nav">').cycle({
        fx:     'turnUp',
        speed:  'fast',
        timeout: 0,
        pager:  '#nav'
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
  <div id="banner1" class="slider"> 
    <div class="contentSlider">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to insert?

Comment: if you can see by default '$('#slider').after('<div id="nav"class="nav">')' the **div#nav** insert after **#slider** I want to change the location, i want it to insert that **div** after or inside '.contentSlider'

Comment: You should be careful when using identical classes and ID's. It might be confusing after a while. You can change the ID to `main-nav` or `secondary-nav` for instance. Also, you might want to use the HTML5 `<nav>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('.contentSlider').append('<div id="nav" class="nav">...</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert an element than you can make use of [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method.

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

`.inner` is class selector .. you can replace it with the selector you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.contentSlider').html('<div id="nav" class="nav">')
```

Comment: this will delete all the existing content of .contentSlider,not recommended